# how to add values of a column in dataframe to another dataframe based on common values? pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Two dataframes:

df1:

```
Name
Sarah   
John   
J   
Fritz
Sarah
John
```

df2:

```
F_Name     gender   count
Sarah      F       1000
John       M       3500
Fritz      M       12540
```

**Aim**: if df1.name is in df2.F_Name then add column gender to df1. The expected answer is:

df1:

```
Name     gender
Sarah     F
John      M
J   
Fritz     M
Sarah     F
John      M
```

below code gives error: "Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer"

```
df1['gender'] = df2[df1['Name'].isin(df2['Name'])]['gender'].values
```

Comment: `df.join(df2.set_index('Name'),on='Name')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `merge`

```
df = df1.merge(df2.rename(columns = {'F_Name':'Name'}), on ='Name',how='left')
```